# stage.show() command changes value of Bounds

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing an application with JavaFX. I want to be able to add `Chart`s to a `Scene` during running the application and work with the `Bounds` of their `.chart-plot-background` child.

Consider the following two code snippets with their outputs:

**Code 1**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Test8 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        AnchorPane anchorPane=new AnchorPane();

        Scene scene=new Scene(anchorPane,600,400);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();

        LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart=new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(),new NumberAxis());

        Region region= (Region) lineChart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");

        anchorPane.getChildren().add(lineChart);

        System.out.println(region.getBoundsInParent());

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }


}
```

output: `BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:0.0, minZ:0.0, width:0.0, height:0.0, depth:0.0, maxX:0.0, maxY:0.0, maxZ:0.0]`

**Code 2**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Test8 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        AnchorPane anchorPane=new AnchorPane();

        Scene scene=new Scene(anchorPane,600,400);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart=new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(),new NumberAxis());

        Region region= (Region) lineChart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");

        anchorPane.getChildren().add(lineChart);

        stage.show();

        System.out.println(region.getBoundsInParent());

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }


}
```

output: `BoundingBox [minX:38.0, minY:10.0, minZ:0.0, width:443.0, height:346.0, depth:0.0, maxX:481.0, maxY:356.0, maxZ:0.0]`

The only difference between the two snippets is the position of `stage.show()` command.

**Question**

How should I fix *Code 1* such that when a child is added to `anchorPane` *after executing* `stage.show()`, the command `region.getBoundsInParent()` outputs valid results?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, you have posted the exact same two pieces of code twice. Regardless, this whole combination of a lookup followed by manually getting the bounds of the region is almost certainly the wrong approach to whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Calling `show()` the first time on the stage applies CSS and generates a layout pass, which sets the sizes for all nodes.  If you want to manually apply CSS and generate a layout pass, then see the information in the duplicate on how to do that.

Comment: Note that the duplicate shows how to do what you are literally asking for, but it is almost certainly not the correct thing to be doing in the first place. Why do you need the bounds of the plot area? If you are adding nodes to the plot area or positioning nodes within it, the supported approach is to subclass `LineChart` and override `layoutPlotChildren()`. You can use, e.g. `getDisplayPosition()` on the axes to find the appropriate layout position for nodes relative to the axis values. This just seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38885893/2189127, which may be a better approach to whatever it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @James_D, my apologies. I noticed that I had copied the same code snippet for both Code 1 and Code 2. The reason I need the bounds of the plot area is part of a problem that **how to find the relative positions of a chart's components (e.g. plot area, x axis, y axis, tick marks, tick labels, etc.) w.r.t. the bounds of the chart itself?**. For example, I would like to know if it is possible to compute the size and position of the plot area (or x axis) w.r.t. the chart bounds.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I suggest asking a new question, that actually asks how to do what you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @jewelsea, thanks for the feedback. I will reformat my question on another post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I truly understand the issue correctly, but if I do, I would use `setOnMouseEntered` or something similar.

Example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        AnchorPane anchorPane=new AnchorPane();

        Scene scene=new Scene(anchorPane,600,400);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart=new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(),new NumberAxis());
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(lineChart);
        lineChart.setOnMouseEntered((event) -> {
            Region region= (Region) lineChart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
           
            System.out.println(region.getBoundsInParent());
        });
        
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach and viewpoint. In my application, it is still possible that the mouse never enters the linechart and the setOnMouseEntered method never runs.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz you need to do a better job of providing information on constraints and operation and requirements in your original question, so that you are able to receive relevant answers.